# Url with IP address is accessible, url using alias instead of IP is not accessible

Tags: authentication, web, ip, alias

The basic issue is in IE on my machine, a particular web site in our intranet doesn't work when using the server name alias.  It does, however work when using the IP address of the server.

```
This doesn’t work 
http://MyWeb/TheSite
```

It's a 401 error in the IIS Logs on the server 
and IE shows "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.  Diagnose Connection Problems".

```
But this does work:
http://100.100.100.100/TheSite 
(100.100.100.100 being a made up IP)

On other machines on our intranet, this does work for me:
http://MyWeb/TheSite
```

I think we've narrowed it down the Integrated Auth on IIS. When I change the AppPool for MyWebb/TheSite to Anonymous on the server, TheSite works on my machine as well as other machines.  When I change back to Integrated Auth it works for me on other machines machines but not my machine.  Any ideas?  Something with my desktop profile?

And another bit of data, TheSite used to work on my machine with Integrated Auth.  It just stopped a couple weeks ago.
Also, we've looked at all the relevent DNS properties, etc, and that all looks good

Comment: When you say your local box, what does "doesn't work" mean, exactly? Error message, crash dump, ??

Comment: @David....good point.  It's a 401 error in the IIS Logs on the server and IE shows "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Comment: Sounds like you are explicitly not being authenticated to the site. When it works "for you" on "other" machines, I'm guessing  (betting?) that you're attempting the access with the "other person" logged in, which effectively means they are the ones being authenticated. Sounds like perhaps some downstream group membership has changed, perchance?

Comment: @David...actually on the "other" machines, I am logging in with my intranet credentials.  The same credentials I use to log into my machine.

Comment: Hmmm...well, then, I'd almost suspect IE on your local box is not providing the proper WWW-Authenticate header, perhaps because (somehow?) your local box was inadvertently moved to a different zone, or that "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" is unchecked on the "Advanced" tab of IE's Internet Options...? Spitballing here, of course :)

Comment: @David...I hear ya, we're spit balling too.  Enable Integrated Windows Authentication is checked on my box.  How would I identify the zone my box is on?

Comment: @David....other users are experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Hmmm...is there any substatus in the logs for the 401? Eg right after the 401 should be another number. That specifies the particular kind of "Unauthorized" failure the webserver is kicking out. Might help.

Comment: @David...yep, it's 401 2 5 0

Comment: Any chance some of the failing machines are going through a proxy server, where the "working" ones are not?

Comment: @David...it's possible.  I'll have to ask the network guys.  My guess would be no, as the person in the office right next to me has no issue, while a person in another building is having the issue.  But you never know.

Comment: Short of that, or mixed-and-matched (and some really old) versions of IE that can't do Integrated Authentication (can't negotiate auth protocol), or something awry in the authentication protocol on the IIS server itself has got to be in play. Normally that 401.2 means one of those three general things. What version of IIS are you running, and which flavor of IE are you using?

Comment: @David....just got back from a mtg.  My IE is Version 8, server IIS is 7.5

Comment: Perhaps you could post a quick screencap of your App's Advanced Settings, the Authentication settings, and its host AppPool settings...might reveal something.

Comment: Hey, @MikeTWebb, you might also check the browser's security settings for the Local Intranet zone and ensure 'Automatic log on to intranet site with username and password' is checked under User Authentication. That could very well be the real problem.

Comment: @David...yep, that setting is checked

Comment: Then I'm back to posting screen shots of the apppool config, and the sites authentication settings. This is bizarre.